# How to restrict Jenkins users to do production deployment using Jenkins RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I already installed and configured `RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy`. I am trying to restrict people based on `globalRoles`. I have a prod role and in that role, I have a list of people responsible to do prod deployments. Also, I have `admin` role that contains a list of admins.

I have Jenkins Global Library that should restrict people based on a library.

```
def trigerUser = 'fsadykov'
def environment = "prod" 
def prodRole = ["user1", "user2", "user3"]


if (trigerUser in prodRole ) {
    println("You are allowed to do prod deployments!!")
} else {
    if (environment != 'prod') {
        println("You are alowed to do this trigger")
    } else {
        println("You are not allowed to do prod deployments!!")
    }
}
```

How I can get the list of people from Jenkins? I need some example to get people from **prodRole**

I did research and it turns out I can do an API call to below endpoint but I think should be an easy way to get that list using `RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy` class to get

Endpoint: `role-strategy/strategy/getRole?type=globalRoles&roleName=prodTeam`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem for now by checking administrator access using the following script. This is not perfect but it's working for now. It would be great if we can checking by specific global role member

```
import hudson.model.Hudson
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy    


def isAdmin(username) {
    def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
    return instance.getAuthorizationStrategy().getACL(User.get(username))
    .hasPermission(User.get(username).impersonate(), hudson.model.Hudson.ADMINISTER)
}


def trigerUser = 'fsadykov'
def environment = "prod" 

if (isAdmin(trigerUser)) {
    println("You are allowed to do prod deployments!!")
} else {
    println("You are not allowed to do prod deployments!!")
}
```